# FaceTime uses mobile data even when good Wi-Fi is available

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi, facetime

Often when I use FaceTime it will run over mobile data, even when a good working Wi-Fi is available. And this always with the same Wi-Fi

Wi-Fi Assist is turned off as recommended in this [Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218935/using-mobile-data-while-connected-to-wifi).

At the moment I'm turning on Airplane Mode, to definitely use Wi-Fi. Works always without any problems and the connection is always great! Of course I forget it from time to time, so it uses my mobile data....

Turning off the cellular for FaceTime is also no option. I live in another country than the rest of my family. So they usually call me over FaceTime and I want to be always available.

This whole thing started some months ago, with some update. I didn't noticed it immediately.

Maybe I'm missing out on something easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Wi-Fi assist turned on? I had a similar problem and turning it off helped a lot. I've noticed that iPhones can often have problems accurately deciding between a fast Wi-Fi network and a strong cellular connection

[image]

EDIT: Whoops. I just realized that you said you already had turned it off. It might be worth resetting your network settings under Settings > General > Transfer or Reset > Reset > Reset Network Setting

Comment: You can update your answer if the information in the comment is relevant. Then it's all contained. Comments may be removed at any point.

Comment: I will try to reset the Network! Thanks a lot! Now I just need to wait for the next FaceTime call! :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Cellular > toggle FaceTime to off:

[image]

Comment: But in this case my family could call me over FaceTime, when I wouldn't be connected with Wi-Fi, right? In worst case I will just accept that, but I also would love to figure out why FaceTime is doing this in the first place (going over cellular instead of Wi-Fi).

Comment: Note: my screen-cap above shows Cellular _turned on_ for face time. You need to slide the switch to the left to disable it. By turning off Cellular for FaceTime, only WiFi will be used for FaceTime. Sorry if this was confusing.